# URL params filter JSON with an OR

Tags: json, http, url, parameters

How do I filter an API request using `or`?

At the moment my API url looks like this:

```
https://someurl.com/....&page=1&limit=100&signal=all&status=open
```

There are two types of status, `open` and `closed`. By default if I dont have the `status=`, it only returns those with `open`. I want to return both though.

This doesnt work - `status=open&status=closed`

Answer (score 0):

Obviously depends on the API. Check the docs if the API vendor supports such operations, if they don't, request all entries regardless of their status and filter on your end.